# consume HTTPS API in Angular

Tags: c#, angular

```ts
var urlNextThink = 'https:XXXXXXX:1671/2/query?platform=windows&platform=mac_os&query=(select (id name) (from device))&format=json';


let headers = new Headers({ 'Accept': 'application/json' });

headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET');
headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type,Accept');
headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa('XXX' + ':' + 'XXX'));
//headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa('demo' + ':' + 'demo'));

let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers, withCredentials: true });
return this.http
  .get(urlNextThink, options)
  .map(res => console.log(res));
```

I am getting Error 401 (unauthorized). Earlier when I was call this API using Asp.net I had to add below line in code then same error 401 (unauthorized) was fixed. I believe SSL is restricting to authenticate API.

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate(object s, X509Certificate Certificate, X509Chain Chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
        { return true; };
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure on server side like this way

```
HttpConfiguration config;
```

if url is same as request url then

```
config.EnableCors();
```

if not then

```
config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*"));
```